# Google map infowindow ajax load content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, infowindow

I am having trouble getting an infowwindow loading from an ajax call
The data comes from a json array
This is the loop code...

```
function getResults(map){
    //remove all existing markers
    deleteOverlays();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    //set search center
    c = map.center;
    var cLat = c.lat().toFixed(6);
    var cLng = c.lng().toFixed(6);

    //get search radius
    var radius = $("#radius option:selected").val()

    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/search_radius.php?lat="+cLat+"&lng="+cLng+"&radius="+radius,
        cache:false,
        async:true,
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            var l = data.markers.length;//alert(l);
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[i][3], data.markers[i][4]);
                var pin = 'images/pins/' + data.markers[i][1] + '.png';
                //alert(pin);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    panControl: false,
                    map:map,
                    icon:pin
                });
                bounds.extend(point);

                map.fitBounds(bounds);

                //add to valid array
                markersArray.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.close();
                    load_content(this,'5');
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

This is the function to load the content

```
function load_content(marker, id){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/get_infowindow_content.php?id='+id,
    cache:true,
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data){
      infowindow.setContent(data);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  });
}
```

The problem I am having is passing the id of the marker to the function (the above shows even setting an ID expliciltly still returns undefined when the php file is run eg

```
load_content(this,'5');
```

I have also tried..(amongst other variations)

```
load_content(this, data.markers[i][0]);
```

Amended to the following which still returns undefined for the id

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   alert (id); //returns undefined
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/get_infowindow_content.php?",
            data:{
                'id':id
            },
            success: function(data){
                infowindow.setContent(data);
                infowindow.setOptions({
                position: marker.getPosition()
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);      
        }
  });



                    //infowindow.close();
                    //load_content(this,'5');
                });
```

Comment: What exactly returns "undefined"? Have you checked that the id-parameter will be passed to the php-script(maybe the php-script doesn't work as expected)? So far the script looks fine, the only thing I miss is the creation of `infowindow`.

Comment: If I check with firebug the post is get_infowindow_content.php?id=undefined

There is a global variable var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); created when the page initializes

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Use `return`

```
return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data:{
            'id':id
        },
        success: function(data){// function to be called if the request succeeds
            infowindow.setContent(data); //set the contents on infowindow
            infowindow.setOptions({
                position: marker.getPosition()
                });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);      
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unless I am still doing something wrong, that doesnt work. The id of the marker is not being passed from the addListener click function

Comment: Did you try to `alert`ing  `id`  before doing `AJAX`??

Comment: Added the code as I understood it to the original question, still returning undefined. If I add alert (data.markers[i][0]) before the addlistener event the id is correct.

Comment: Whether your `load_content` function is calling? try to `alert` `id` in this function

Comment: load_content is no longer being called, I thought the return function removed the need for that?